# Routing issue between raspberry and internet

Tags: linux, networking, routing, raspberry-pi

Here is my setup

[image]

I have a raspberry pi who's connected to my windows 7 desktop using a RJ45 patch. My desktop can access to internet using WiFi but my raspberry pi can't. Still, my raspberry pi can get to my desktop.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/$ ping 192.168.50.10
PING 192.168.50.10 (192.168.50.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.50.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.360 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.330 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.337 ms
^C
--- 192.168.50.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.330/0.342/0.360/0.019 ms
```

A route exists from my desktop to the router :

```
C:\Users\Will>route print
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.72     25
```

Also I have set the desktop as the gateway for the raspberry pi and created a default route pointing to 192.168.50.10

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.50.10   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.50.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

What am I missing ? To me that should work but I can't ping 192.168.1.1 from the raspberry pi.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/$ traceroute 192.168.1.1
traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is activate ICS (Internet Connection Sharing).

To do it, enable checkbox "Allow Other Network Users to Connect through This Computer’s Internet Connection" on windows wireless adapter.

[image]

[How to Share an Internet Connection in Windows 7](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7/)